# android - string.xml parsing error

Tags: android, xml-parsing

i have made a string named info_data as follows

```
<string name="info_address">SVG Service Verlags GmbH & Co. KG\n
    Schwertfegerstra?e 1-3\n
    D-23556 L?beck\n
</string>
```

i am getting an xml error saying that

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity 
     reference.
    - error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

this error comes on the first line containing the &.

what is going wrong and how do i fix it.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't use the & sign.  Try `&amp;` (I haven't tested it but it may work).

Answer (score 5):

I believe you will need to change the `&` to `&amp;`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<string
        name="info_address">SVG Service Verlags GmbH &amp; Co. KG\n Schwertfegerstra?e 1-3\n
        D-23556 L?beck\n</string>
```

copy paste the code i have pasted.
use this string use `&amp;` instead of &

Answer (score 3):

While other answers about the ampersand may be correct, I don't think its just that.

[This should be of some use.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

> Where an attribute value is a string, double backslashes ('\') must be used to escape characters — for example, '\n' for a newline or '\uxxxx' for a Unicode character.

You have \n, which may need to be \\n in addition to the change to the &

Comment: You should replace the \n with \\n, and put &amp; in place of the &

Comment: can't someone before you said the same thing. i gotta mark his answer because it came first.

Comment: Did you not also need to escape the newline?